# "Fitted" windows with large internal gaps - any workarounds?

Tags: windows, gap

We recently contracted an established UK window fitting company with credible references to change our windows. From my unexperienced eye, they look well fitted from the outside, however there are considerable gaps on the inside between the frame and the walls. Below are photos of the worst such instance, on the top there is a ~27mm gap between the window frame and the wall on the inside. Is that acceptable? I should add that the previous owners had wooden architraves around the previous aluminium frames, so I consider it not impossible that the window enclave has internally different sizes, but I have zero expertise on such matters.

In theory, I could complain to the company, I haven't formally signed off the installation, though we are quite exhausted with all the renovations and would consider a cosmetic solution if it's feasible. The plasterer says he cannot close such a large gap, and I wouldn't want it either. My thought was to cover the gaps using uPVC architraves, my only concern is that this may create a cold spot behind the architraves and will lead to condensation and mould. When I feel into the gap, it doesn't feel colder than the rest, but that's not a very scientific assessment I admit.

Anyone got any ideas what's the best way forward? We're very new to this whole world, so any advice will be much appreciated. Thank you!

[image: Gap on the inside]
[image: Windows from the outside]

Comment: What does your window contract say about inside finishing/trim?

Comment: It says: "fitted to foam and cut back inside leaving for plastering". The plasterer says it cannot be plastered, the gaps are too wide, which sounds sensible too me.

Comment: They need a trim or for the plaster board to butt against or go under it even. Since the outside fits, I  dont think your contractor stuffed it up. The gap was too wide originally.

Comment: Thank you, Rohit, that sounds sensible. Do you think a quadrant trim would be a suitable solution?